# How to send a mail notification using C# code

Tags: c#-4.0

I have used the below code to send the mail notifications using the C# code

```
public static void SendNotification(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient mailServer = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"], int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portnumber"]));
                mailServer.EnableSsl = true;
                mailServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sender_username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sender_password"]);
                string from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sender"];
                string to = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receipients"];
                string cc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receipientCC"];
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
                msg.Subject = "Branch API Export Results";
                msg.Body = "Test Mail. Please Find Attached for the Results from Branch API Export";
                msg.CC.Add(cc);
                msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(filepath));
                mailServer.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log
            }
        }
```

Included the configuration values in the App.Config. Any better way other than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is.

```
 private static void SendMail(string subject, string content)
{
    try

    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("YOURMAİL");
        mail.To.Add("MAİLTO");
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = content;
        SmtpServer.Port = 25;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("YOURMAİL", "YOURMAİLPASSWORD");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

This is simplest way to send mail. Don't forget to add using System.Net.Mail;